# Moscow to Istanbul by train

Tags: trains, russia, turkey, istanbul, moscow

i am in Moscow now fan ID electronic and wants to travel to Istanbul,what document do i need to travel with from Moscow to Istanbul by train?

Comment: What country's passport do you have?

Comment: And which route are you planning to travel? Train travel to Istanbul in general, and international connections to and from Turkey are currently severely restricted due to construction works on the Turkish railway network.

Comment: As I see it, the [train route through Georgia and Azerbaijan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baku%E2%80%93Tbilisi%E2%80%93Kars_railway) is not yet ready. So depending on your nationality, you will need your passport and tourist visas for Ukraine, Moldova, Schengen (from the Romanian embassy) and Turkey.

Comment: @Alexander: Romania isn't part of the Schengen agreement (yet).

Comment: Alternately, you could take a [ferry from Sochi to Trabzon](http://www.ferrylines.com/ferries/search-results/operator/OLYM/?no_cache=1) and you wouldn't need any transit visas, as you'd pass straight from Russia to Turkey.  I don't know what the status is for the Sevastopol–Istanbul ferry since the Russian takeover of Crimea.

Answer (score 2):

[rail.cc](https://rail.cc/en/train/moscow-to-istanbul) shares that there are three different travel routes between Moscow and Istanbul, each through varied countries for which you'd have to check your visa requirements, depending on your nationality.

1. Moscow (Russia) - Chisinau (Moldova) - Bucharest (Romania) - Istanbul (Turkey)
2. Moscow (Russia) - Warsaw (Poland) - Budapest (Hungary) - Bucharest (Romania) - Istanbul (Turkey)
3. Moscow (Russia) - Kiev (Ukraine) - Budapest (Hungary) - Bucharest (Romania) - Istanbul (Turkey)

> railcc is NOT a ticket booking engine. We are an independent project of some friends. We explain you[r] train travel routes, where and how to buy the best train tickets and rail passes. We add new connections every day.

Comment: How far will you currently get with the train from Bucharest? All current information I am able to find confirms that international services to and from Istanbul Sirkeci (the main railway station in the European part of Istanbul) are still interrupted.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo with an oddly-phrased question, and no nationality indicated, I felt it was more 'how' rather than 'can' .... Your advisory may prompt OP to reconsider.

Comment: Also, you're missing a few transit countries in this list: The first also goes through Ukraine and Bulgaria, the second goes through Belarus, probably Czechia, and Bulgaria with the third also going through Bulgaria.